# Memory error on Random Forest Classifier prediction

Tags: python, classification

I have fitted a Random Forest Classifier on my dataset containing 7 features and about 1 million rows or records.

Following is my code.

```
randForestClassifier=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10,max_depth=3)
randForestClassifier.fit(X_train,y)
pred=randForestClassifier.predict(featues_test)
```

I am getting Memory error when I use predict method of my classifier.How to fix it?

Following is my complete log

```
randForestClassifier.predict(featues_test)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-15-0b7612d6e958>", line 1, in <module>
    randForestClassifier.predict(featues_test)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py", line 462, in predict
    proba = self.predict_proba(X)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py", line 513, in predict_proba
    for e in self.estimators_)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 659, in __call__
    self.dispatch(function, args, kwargs)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 406, in dispatch
    job = ImmediateApply(func, args, kwargs)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 140, in __init__
    self.results = func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py", line 106, in _parallel_helper
    return getattr(obj, methodname)(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py", line 592, in predict_proba
    proba = self.tree_.predict(X)

  File "sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx", line 3207, in sklearn.tree._tree.Tree.predict (sklearn\tree\_tree.c:24468)

  File "sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx", line 3209, in sklearn.tree._tree.Tree.predict (sklearn\tree\_tree.c:24340)

MemoryError
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are getting the `MemoryError` at `randForestClassifier.predict(featues_test)`, as shown by the stack trace:

```
File "<ipython-input-15-0b7612d6e958>", line 1, in <module>
    randForestClassifier.predict(featues_test)
```

The remaining lines of the stack trace shows that the problems comes from `sklearn`, in the C code: `sklearn\tree\_tree.c:24340`

Comment: Have you tried pushing less than 1 million rows ? Depending of the memory size and the size of one row, you can easily reach high memory size.  If a row is 1000 bytes in memory, you  get 10GB of data to store in RAM.

Comment: I sliced 10000 Rows and it worked perfect........but now what about those  full data, those 1 million rows?

Comment: Increase your memory size, or use another tool handling big amount of data. Maybe you will find something [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html).

Comment: but my memory is already very big it is 16 GB and when I ran this it still showed 10 GB available?

Comment: 32bit or 64bit system ? You need to be careful with the tools installed, for instance anaconda, which should be used in 64bits version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108328/discussion-between-naseer-ahmed-and-aluriak).

Comment: Hi All, Is there any solution for this Memory Error ? I think it should work well in AWS with GPU support